# RoR: using Dropzone.js with jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable, dropzone.js

I have Dropzone Js combined with paperclip in my rails app, I have also managed to apply jquery's sortable to it.

my objective is:

1. to be able to save every image's position to the db on
   upload success
2. update the position for each image in the db when I change (sort) the order of the images.

my upload model has :image and :position
and my routes has collection {post "sort"}

my controller code:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def upload_list
    @uploads = Upload.all.select(:id, :image_file_name, :image_file_size).order("position")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: @uploads.to_json(methods: [:path])}
    end
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.create(upload_params)
    @upload.position = params[:upload][:position]

    if @upload.save
      render json: { message: "success", fileID: @upload.id }, :status => 200
    else
      render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end
  end

  def sort
    //params[:upload] gives undefined method for nil error 
    Upload.all.each_with_index do |id, index|
      Upload.where(id: id).update_all({position: index+1})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end

  def destroy
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
    if @upload.destroy
      render json: { message: "File deleted from server" }
    else
      render json: { message: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',') }
    end
  end

  private
    def upload_params
      params.require(:upload).permit(:image, :position)
    end
end
```

upload.rb:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",:thumb => "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment :image,
                   :presence => true,
                   :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
                   :size => { :less_than => 1.megabyte } 

  def path
    image.url
  end

  def as_json(options = { })
    h = super(options)
    h["name"] = h.delete "image_file_name"
    h["size"] = h.delete "image_file_size"
    h
  end

end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Uploads#new</h1>

<%= form_for(@upload, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="fallback">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and finally uploads.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  $("#new_upload").dropzone({
    maxFilesize: 1,
    paramName: "upload[image]",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: "Delete",

    //to show existing images from db 
    init: function() {
      var thisDropZone = this;
      $.getJSON('upload_list', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
          var mockFile = { name: val.name, size: val.size };
          thisDropZone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
          thisDropZone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, val.path);
          $(mockFile.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', val.id);

          // adding id attribute for serialize
          $(".dz-preview:last-child").attr('id', "image_" + val.id);
        });
      });
    },

    success: function(file, response){
      $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);
      $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");

      var order = $('.dropzone').sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uploads/sort',
        data: order,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }        
      });
    },

    removedfile: function(file){
      var id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id');
      file.previewElement.remove();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/uploads/' + id,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data.message);
        }
      });

      var order = $('.dropzone').sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uploads/sort',
        data: order,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }        
      });
    }
  });

 //this function is for sorting + updating positions of old images loaded by the init function.
  $(function() {
    $(".dropzone").sortable({
      items:'.dz-preview',
      cursor: 'move',
      opacity: 0.5,
      containment: '.dropzone',
      distance: 20,
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var order = $('.dropzone').sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/uploads/sort',
          data: order,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }        
        });
      }
    });
    $(".dropzone").disableSelection();
  });
});
```

I know I got lots of cleaning up to do but I'm trying to get it to work first.

I understand that I need an id preceded by an "_" in each image's .dz-preview of dropzone for serialize to work. However the ajax post in the success function is working fine without applying any id attribute, so when I upload 3 images, in the db the positions are 1, 2 and 3 respectively, also the removedfile function works, if i remove the second image, image1 gets position "1" and image3 gets the position attribute updated to 2, thanks to the sort method in the controller.

what I tried is add a line in the init function to append the id attribute to .dz-preview  and refresh the page so that i test the init function and tried the sorting again, but its the same, what I get is:

```
Started POST "/uploads/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-12 12:47:39 +0200
Processing by UploadsController#sort as */*
Parameters: {"image"=>["318", "320", "319"]}
Upload Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads"
SQL (5.4ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "position" = 1 WHERE "uploads"."id" = 318
SQL (14.7ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "position" = 2 WHERE "uploads"."id" = 319
SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "position" = 3 WHERE "uploads"."id" = 320
Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 29.6ms)
```

notice the order of the parameters so image "318" should take position 1, "320" should take position 2 and "319" should take position 3...but as shown the new order is ignored from the update...

any ideas what I'm missing? is it the sort method or the .sortable function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your sort action with following code.

```
  def sort
    images = Upload.where(id: params[:image])
    images.each do |image|
      if position = params[:image].index(image.id.to_s)
        image.update_attribute(:position, position + 1) unless image.position == position
      end 
    end 
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Comment: makes sense, but it seems now the method is not getting any ids?
  Parameters: {"image"=>["319", "320", "318"]}
  Upload Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE "uploads"."id" IS NULL

Comment: updated answer, it should be params[:image] instead params[:upload]

Comment: I added an extra "=" in the if statement but I also noticed position is not defined, I assumed you meant if image.position but i don't think thats the case because ur comparing image.position with position within the if statement...so what should position be defined as?

Comment: im surprised the code is working with updating the sorting despite not defining position and the single "=" in the if statement, will you please explain it to me? 
also there is a problem now that positions are not inserted into the db when I first upload an image. it only works when I refresh the page to retrieve the images and start sorting...

Comment: I am assigning position variable to index of image id, do not change it to comparison

Comment: oh i see! awesome. i get it now. also for the position save on uploading part, I did not append the image id in the success function. so now i did and that part works now too. thanks a lot for your help!